# How can I make a one row from 1 group using oracle statement

Tags: sql, oracle, grouping

There is a group as below.

```
 refno | col1 | col2
---------------------
   1   |   a  |  aa 
   1   |   b  |  bb
   1   |   c  |  cc
   1   |   d  |  dd
```

I want to make it like this using Oracle SQL:

```
refno   a     b    c    d    
1       aa    bb   cc   dd
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 6):

You can do it using `PIVOT`

```
WITH sel AS
  (SELECT 1 refno , 'a' col1 , 'aa' col2 FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 , 'b' , 'bb' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 , 'c' , 'cc' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 , 'd' , 'dd' FROM dual
  )
SELECT * 
FROM sel
PIVOT 
(max(col2)
FOR col1 IN ('a','b','c','d'))
```

But you have to specify `col1` values manually - `FOR col1 IN ('a','b','c','d')`

More - [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/analysis.htm#DWHSG0209)